# Intersection type prevents compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs

I am posting because I am experiencing troubles with Intersection Types in TypeScript.

So here is the context: in this project, the team would like to integrate Lodash, as it would allow us to memoize a lot of code. We use **TypeScript** in **Webstorm 10.0.4** and compile with **grunt-typescript**. We retrieved the definition file *lodash.d.ts*, but, as it contains a lot of Intersection Types (like `debounce(...): T & Cancelable`), we cannot compile our project.

We looked through google but haven't found any solution so far. Is it because of the Webstorm version ? The **grunt-typescript** node module ? We really need some help on this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we cannot compile our project.

If you are using `grunt-typescript` to do the compilation, then that is the place which you need to fix.

> We retrieved the definition file lodash.d.ts, but, as it contains a lot of Intersection Types (like debounce(...): T & Cancelable)

Seems like the grunt-typescript version you are using is using an old version of the compiler. If you have the chance give https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/ a go. It always ships with the latest stable TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

We are going to try a newer version of grunt-typescript, and if it does not work we will try grunt-ts.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the grunt-typescript node module and it works now :)